# change css dropdown sub menu font size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching to find the answer for this, but without luck. I have a drop down menu where I want the font size of the sub menu to be smaller. I can get part of it to change sizes but on the hover I am pretty sure it is inheriting the styling from the nav bar. When I change the size that is on the nav bar the sub menu font size changes, but so does the nav bar hover, which is no good. I have tried several work arounds in the style sheet but nothing seems to be able to over ride the nav bar.

Right now I have the following working:

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a class="page-scroll dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Christy Lodge<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">View Our Rooms</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Room Request Form</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Map-Christy Lodge</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Policies/Procedures</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
```

The page url is at:

```
http://www.dinewine.com/startbootstrap-agency-1.0.6/index.html
```

It is the last menu item.  I want the sub menu font to be 10px and the hover to be 10 px as well.

I am sure I will get close to fixing this, but any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks so much. -Beth

Comment: What did you try? Can you give some CSS that you think it should work but not success?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your css, something like this should work:

```
.navbar-default .nav .dropdown-menu li a,
.navbar-default .nav .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hello Marco - Thank you! That worked perfectly. I am not exactly sure how this works, but I think it has something to do with adding css that works over the controlling nav bar elements?

Comment: Problem was the selector `.navbar-default .nav li a:hover, .navbar-default .nav li a:focus` was more specific than the one you were using. Check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Great. Thank you Marco. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Adding classes to everything is good practice - especially if you ever want to change the CSS without refactoring your HTML.

But you can target the sub-menu like so:

```
.dropdown li { font-size: 12px; }
```

This targets all `li` that are nested within `.dropdown`. There are some other selectors that are really useful, too. Check out the [Lobotomized Owl](http://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls) for a larger list, but this is immediately relevant:

`li > li`: targets an `li` that is the immediate child of another (not one that is nested two or more levels below - like, grandchildren or whatever).